# Test Crashed Caught unexpected signal: 6 on CodeWars in C

Tags: c

I have done a code to solve the [Sum String as Numbers](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5324945e2ece5e1f32000370/train/c) problem on `CodeWars`.

On my machine it runs and returns the correct value, it also passes all tests on CodeWars, but for some reasons it's raised the `Caught unexpected signal: 6` and `free(): invalid pointer`.

I have checked other questions related to this and other forums but it seems that i don't anything form there. I have used only `size_t` my pointer don't increase like `a++` or anything in order to `free` to not be able to dealocate memory.

---

My code consists on:

1. a function `char *to_num(const char *a,size_t *size)` which converts all digits from ASCII to numbers (i.e. '3' => 3) and returns a `char*` to a dynamic allocated array with all that numbers. Also it removes all prefixed zeros.
2. `void no_zeros(char *a)` which simply deletes all the *0* from the start of a string (i.e. "0012" => "12")
3. a custom `len` function, because i use a different nul character, as my `0` in array is tehnically 0 digit. On this example i use `10` as terminating character
4. `char *fill(char* a,size_t size)` that returns a string prefixed with as many zeros as needed to reach the length `size` (i.e. for `a="12"` and `size=4` it returns `0012`)
5. and finnaly the main function `char *strsum(const char *a, const char *b)` which returns the sum written as a string (i.e. "123" + "456" returns "579")

The flow of this program goes like:

- convert the strings received as parameter to *numbers* with `to_num`
- if one *number* is longer than another the `fill` function is called to complet the smaller one so that we can perform the addition
- than we perform the addition per components and return the number as string

- I have a bug that prefixes my result with zero so i call the `no_zeros` on resut.

---

My code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

void display(const char *a,size_t size){
    for(size_t i=0;a[i]!=0 && i<size;i++){
        if(a[i]>'0'){
            printf("%c",a[i]);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d",a[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

char *to_num(const char *a,size_t *size){
    
    
    size_t i=0,j=0;
    *size = strlen(a);
    
    char *result = malloc((*size+1)*sizeof(char));
    if(result==NULL){return 0;}

    while(a[i]=='0'){i++;}

    while(a[i]!=0){
        result[j] = a[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    result[j]=0;

    *size = j;

    for(size_t i=0;i<*size;i++){
        result[i] = result[i]-'0';
    }
    result[*size] =10;
    
    return result;
}




void no_zeros(char *a){
    size_t i=0,j=0;

    while(a[i]=='0'){i++;}

    while(a[i]!=0){
        a[j] = a[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    a[j]=0;
    
}

size_t len(char *a){
    size_t s=0;
    for(size_t i=0;a[i]!=10;i++){
        s++;
    }
    return s;
}


char *fill(char* a,size_t size){
    size_t a_size = len(a);
    
    char *copy = malloc((size+2)*sizeof(char));
    if(copy==NULL){return 0;}
    
    for(size_t i=0;i<size-a_size;i++){
        copy[i] = 0;
    }
    for(size_t i=0;i<a_size;i++){
        copy[i+size-a_size] = a[i];
    }
    
    
    copy[size] = 0;
    for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++){
    }
    return copy;
}

char *strsum(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    size_t size_a,size_b,bigger,smaller;
    
    char *x,*y;
    
    
    x = to_num(a,&size_a);
    y = to_num(b,&size_b);
    
    bigger = size_a>=size_b  ? size_a : size_b;
    smaller = size_a<=size_b ? size_a : size_b;
    
    if(bigger != smaller){
        if(bigger == size_a){
            y = fill(y,bigger);
            size_b = bigger;
        }
        else{
            x = fill(x,bigger);
            size_a = bigger;
        }
    }
 
    char *result = malloc((bigger+2)*sizeof(char));
    if(result==NULL){return 0;}
    int carry=0;
    size_t i;
    for(i=bigger;i>=0;i--){
        result[i] = (x[i-1]+y[i-1]+carry)%10+'0';
        carry = (x[i-1]+y[i-1]+carry)/10;
        if(i==0) break;
    }
    
    result[bigger+1]=0;
    no_zeros(result);
    if(result[0]==0){return "0";}
    free(x);
    free(y);
    return result;
    
}

int main(){
    printf("%s\n",strsum("9567","800"));
 
    
}
```

Comment: Too much fiddly code to follow... but... With `if(result[0]==0){return "0";}`, the function is returning the address of a string literal sometimes, and an allocated heap address others... This is inconsistent. Either there's a memory leak or CodeWars detects the problem with its cleanup after testing edge cases...

Comment: I see some memory leaks, but the only two `free()`s are valid ones.  Quite possibly you are overrunning the bounds of some of your allocated blocks.  That produces UB, which tends to be of a sort that is particularly likely to cause breakage in the memory allocator.  Check what Valgrind tells you.

Comment: On the other hand, the problem asks for a *function*, not a whole program, so presumably the automated judge will link your function with its own `main()`.  In that event, the issue Rusty raised with returning the address of a string literal is a very likely culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `display()`: `for(size_t i=0;a[i]!=0 && i<size;i++){`: swap the order of the conditions so you do the boundary check before `a[i]`.
2. `strsum()`: `for(i=bigger;i>=0;i--){` doesn't make sense as i is a `size_t` i.e. unsigned and in the loop body you do `x[i-1]` and `y[i-1]` which is wrong when `i` is 0. What about this?

```
    for(i=bigger; i; i--){
        result[i] = (x[i-1]+y[i-1]+carry)%10+'0';
        carry = (x[i-1]+y[i-1]+carry)/10;
    }
    result[0] = carry + '0';
```

3. `strsum()`: `x` and `y` leak as you free them after a return:

```
    free(x);
    free(y);
    if(result[0]==0){return "0";}
```

4. `strsum()`: `to_num()` allocates an array and then `fill()` allocates a copy (2 mallocs) and in `strsum()` you may leak the first `malloc()` for either `x` or `y`:

```
    x = to_num(a,&size_a);
    y = to_num(b,&size_b);

    // ...

    if(bigger != smaller){
        if(bigger == size_a){
            y = fill(y,bigger);
            size_b = bigger;
        }
        else{
            x = fill(x,bigger);
            size_a = bigger;
        }
    }
```

Either `realloc()` in `fill()` instead of creating a copy or use a temporary variable in `strsum()` so you can free the original malloc'ed value:

```
    if(bigger != smaller){
        if(bigger == size_a){
            char *tmp = fill(y, bigger);
            free(y);
            y = tmp;
            size_b = bigger;
        }
        else{
            char *tmp = fill(x, bigger);
            free(x);
            x = tmp;
            size_a = bigger;
        }
    }
```

Btw, this is the same code in both branches so consider writing a function.

5. `main()`: leaks the returned string:

```
int main(){
    char *s = strsum("9567","800");
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
}
```

6. `strsum()`: Once you fix above mention leak in `main()` you can no longer do `return "0"`.  You would need a size check and possible `realloc()` before doing:

```
   return strcpy(result, "0");
```

or you could `free(result); return strdup("0");`.  This is most likely the root cause (in calling test code you don't see).